# Discord.JS Giveaway Timer

Tags: timer, discord.js

I am trying to make a giveaway system in Discord.JS but am having trouble on setting the timer for it. I would use a setTimeout function or component collector but the problem with that is when the bot turns off, and turns back on again the timer fails and stops. Some packages make it so if the bot is turned back on, the timer resumes, which is what I want to do. Can someone help me with this?

I tried doing this:

`setTimeout(() => { // code })`

Comment: There is no way to keep your timer running if you turn the bot off since the script stops running. I recommend using a database (per your choice) and save the end date/start date (again, whatever you prefer). Then you can make a script that checks if the giveaway is done or not. How you do this is all up to you.

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought could work. But where in the code should it check when a giveaway in a server is done?

Comment: You could use a setInterval function in your main file to check the status of the giveaway every X amount of time.

Comment: Ok, thank you! One more thing, I am using the MS package to convert the users input to miliseconds, how can I check if the time is up? Or will it be a timestamp? Then how would I do it?

Comment: I think you should make another question for that.

Comment: Thanks! How do I convert milliseconds to a unix timestamp if there is such thing?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question proposed in the comment thread on the question "Ok, thank you! One more thing, I am using the MS package to convert the users input to miliseconds, how can I check if the time is up? Or will it be a timestamp? Then how would I do it?"

All a unix timestamp is is an integer, which you can check like so:

```js
const over = endDate <= Date.now();
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I convert milliseconds to a unix timestamp if there is such thing?